# pdf to excel - placing itext shapes into excel

Tags: c#, excel, pdf, itext

I am trying to convert a pdf to an excel spreadsheet. I have the code to extract the text with itextsharp ITextChunkLocationStrategy. 
I now have a table with one column with text (split by chunks)and another column with chunks rectangle dimensions and locations. 
I now need to place the text chunks into the right location on an excel document.

[image: table of the two columns containing the text and rectangles]

below is code that i have found on googling. but i do not know any way of telling excel which cells to place the text into  - based on the coordinates

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
   var dty = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
             orderby row.Field<float>("x")
             where row.Field<int>("yRank") == rowNo
               select row);

   var tbl = dty.CopyToDataTable();
   for (int y = 0; y < tbl.Rows.Count; y++)
   {
        ws.Cells[rowNo, y + 1] = tbl.Rows[y]["text"].ToString();
   }
}

rowNo++;
```

Comment: Please include the code that you have attempted so far, so people can help you diagnose specific issues.

Comment: i have included the code. i have come a bit further along in getting to my answer but i am not quite there yet. I can add a shape to an exact location with the text inside it. is there anyway to copy the text from the shape into that cell?  for (int i = 0; i < dtt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    xlWorksheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal,100,1+i,1+i,1+i);
                }